# htaccess redirect goes to wrong URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have setup the following rules in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    // Redirect old blog URLs to new location
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.objectsanduse.com/blog/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.objectsanduse.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    // Wordpress rewrite rules
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The URL `http://www.somedomain.com/blog/2016/01/19/some-post/` redirects correctly to `http://www.somedomain.com/2016/01/19/some-post/`

But `http://www.somedomain.com/blog` redirects to `http://www.somedomain.com//2015/03/30/some-other-post`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you only need a single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog\/?)(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This rule takes any old URI starting with `blog` (optionally followed by a `/`)

and captures everything that follows (where everything includes "nothing at all").

Then it rewrites the URI, containing the second capture group but without the preceding `blog/`.

Comment: It seems that http://www.somedomain.com/blog becomes http://www.somedomain.com/www.somedomain.com - same as @anubhava

Comment: I've tweaked it slightly. It should work perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in this rule:

```
// Redirect old blog URLs to new location
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.objectsanduse.com/blog/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.objectsanduse.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable only matches domain name without `URI`. You can fix that rule by playing:

```
// Redirect old blog URLs to new location
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.objectsanduse\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: It seems that http://www.somedomain.com/blog becomes http://www.somedomain.com/www.somedomain.com

Comment: Tried that already - even tried in incognito mode, I stil have the same problem.

Comment: You should test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled. Then check in Networking tab what 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: My last edit was around 4 hours back. btw your accepted answer also matches `/blog123`